# How DiffTool Extension Works in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have loaded DiffTool extension to compare two versions of a model. I just removed some elements from version 1 and upload it as a 2nd version. Here are the Model Browsers for those versions -

[image]

Now, when I compare these two versions I am getting many differences between the model versions which is much higher than what I expected. The comparison panel shows many items as Added, Removed and Modified. I have seen that though exact same item is present in both models(after the removed item in the model tree), DiffTool showing it as Added and Modified in version 2. Like this -

[image]

From a user point of view, I don't want to see this as an Added or Modified item. From the documentation, I am not clear how DiffTool compares items. Can you please help me to understand the way DiffTool compares models? And If I want to customize the comparison logic, is there any way for this? TIA

Comment: As I know, DiffTool compares properties and bounding-box. I do not know why it shows 0 Removed while you did removed elements. Could you share a demo models with us (in the case you logged by forge.help email)?

Comment: in addition, if you are working with BIM360 or ACC models, a new API might be more useful to you. It provides the diff of models versions.  This is a AU class which will run next week  https://events-platform.autodesk.com/event/autodesk-university-2021/planning/UGxhbm5pbmdfNjcwNDY5

Comment: In the second image two (same in two models) items are selected and they don't have any difference. DiffTool should show 0 removed, 0 added and 0 modified. Isn't it? In the model browser you can see that in the first version(left side) an item is extra which is removed in the second version(right side).

Comment: @XiaodongLiang , I have sent those two models to the help email.

Comment: my apology for late response due to holiday. my colleague Eason has diagnosed your models and found the diff number exceeded 1000, which looks like a limit with the extension. I will try to see if it possible to manage the limit..

Comment: It's fine @XiaodongLiang. But I am thinking, how difftoll finds that much difference? The second version of the model was made by deleting some(93) elements as you can see in the first picture. I was expecting that difftoll will only show some(93) removed items. Not any added or modified items.